# Serializing and deserializing list of large elements one by one

Tags: java, serialization

I have a list of objects that are very large, so I need to transform an element, serialize it, and later, I need to deserialize all elements of a list, but also one by one, because of their size. How can I achive this in Java?

Also, is it perhaps better, if possible, to write a block of elements and read a block, that is small enough to fit in memory, because of the transfer between disk and memory, and how to do that in case of serialization? Let's say I have a list of 1000 elements, and I want to deserialize 10 elements, than next 10 and so on...

Thanks

Comment: Consider using _anything else_ other than Java serialization, if you can. It has some important gotchas.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can you please give some more info about that gotchas, and what else would you recommend?

Comment: I might be able to write up something more than a comment's worth of an answer later. Serialization in this (http://parleys.com/play/514892290364bc17fc56c508) is a good overview.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing a List, you can write the elements of the list individually.

This would allow you to process one element at a time.  You can use buffering to help performance.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that is the thing to do, but can you give code example? I know there is ObjectOutputStream.writeObject, but I think that if I use this method in a loop, it will cause overwriting of serialized objects, and only the last one will be saved. How do I use appending, and how to include buffering? Thanks

Comment: OOS appends and buffers by default.